# iOS: Instagram hook with special characters

Tags: objective-c, instagram

I am trying to open Instagram from my app. The tag should contain some norwegian special characters, but the Instagram app is not lauching when I try to execute the code below. I tried with the code example below, and with UTF8 encoding, but without success. As soon as I add a tag without these characters, Instagram launches. Any tips on how to handle this characters?

```
NSString* hashtag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"instagram://tag?name=øæå"];

 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:hash];
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the percent escapes like this:

```
NSString* hashtag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"instagram://tag?name=%C3%B8%C3%A6%C3%A5"];
```

Comment: Your welcome. For your future tags you can use this online tool: http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/